# Read analog temperature Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, temperature

The conversion formula does not work as expected(21.6 Celsius degree in the room but will return another value of 34 or more depending on the formula used).
I use a KY-013 temperature sensor and the mcp3008 driver. I connected the temperature sensor to the channel 1 of the driver. I connected the driver as mentioned on this website: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-analog-inputs-python-mcp3008/.
I also tried with a humidity soil sensor and it works fine.
The  MCP3008(channel = 1) returns me a value between 0 and 1. How Should I convert it into Celsius degree?

I tried to use the formula mentioned on the datasheet:

```
Temp = math.log(10000.0 * ((1024.0 / RawADC - 1)));
Temp = 1 /(0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * Temp * Temp)) * Temp);
Temp = Temp - 273.15; // convert from Kelvin to Celsius
return Temp;
```

But since Raspberry has value 1 when the channel does not receive anything i replaced `RawADC` with `1 - RawADC`.
It returned somewhere around 34 degrees.. but in the room, I recorded with a thermostat the 21.7 degrees.
I tried other formulas similar to:

```
voltage = 5 * (1 - RawADC)
temp = (voltage / 1024 - 0.5) * 100
#-55 is the minimal temp that the sensor can read
#125 is the maximum
return temp-55
```

or something like:

```
delta_temp = 125 - (-55)
delta_v = 5 - 0
m = delta_temp/delta_V
b = -55 # at point 0 voltage => -55degre 
T = (1 - RawADC) * 5 * m + b
```

I even tried the simple rule of 3 but the result was still NOT as expected.

My current code is:

```
from gpiozero import MCP3008 
from time import sleep
import math


while True:
    #create an object called temp that refers to MCP3008 channe1 
    temp = MCP3008(1) 
    print(temp.value) # display 0.49 or 0.53 depending
    sleep(0.1)
    voltage = (1- temp.value) *5
    Temp = math.log(10000.0 * (1024.0 / voltage - 1))
    Temp = 1 /(0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * Temp * Temp)) * Temp)
    Temp = Temp - 273.15 # convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius
    print(Temp) # display a value over -74
```

[coeficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYp9X.png)

[conversion Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRoki.png)

[main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD4mm.png)

Comment: Are you sure about the Python version? 2.7 is obsolete by now. That said, can you provide a [mcve] with the ADC output hardcoded in there, along with the expected and actual output?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I am sure. I use python 2.7 cause I have an older software version for raspberry software which do not allow installing python3.

Comment: The code is something like:from gpiozero import MCP3008
from time import sleep

#create an object called temp that refers to MCP3008 channe1
Temp = MCP3008(1)
    print(temp.value)#0.49
    sleep(0.1)

Comment: Than I use Temp = math.log(10000.0 * ((1024.0 / ((1- temp.value) *5) - 1)));
Temp = 1 /(0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * Temp * Temp)) * Temp); 
Temp = Temp - 273.15; //and the result is over 90 degree but in the room there are 21

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve it. The code you posted here as comments is nigh unreadable.

Comment: I modified the question. At the end of the message it's also my current code state that refers to the issue

Comment: That is surely not the code you're running.

Comment: I placed 3 pictures of the code related to the issue that I use to ensure I do not mistype something previous

Comment: Copy'n'paste the code you put here into a file and run it. Using copy'n'paste is the proper way to transfer the code, not pictures. Still, we need a [mcve].

Comment: I created a new file on my Raspberry only with the code mentioned in the question (please see my current code). To add the code on my device I used copy-paste method. The results for the first print are around 0.53 and the second print displays a value around -74.38....